# Benifits of using apt, or another command?

Tags: linux

I am setting up a new Linux device and I'm relatively new to Linux, what are the benefits of using apt for things? is there any other command that is better than apt?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about linux system administration. It belongs on http://askubuntu.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apt is the default package manager on Debian derivatives (like Ubuntu). There are other alternatives like yum (which is the default on the RH family of distros like Fedora). A discussion of "better" or "worse" won't make much sense to you if you're new to Gnu/Linux.